# jQuery Select2 Ajax with preload data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I am using a jQuery Plugin [Select 2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/). With the settings I am using, I allow "Multiple" selects from an Ajax response which is linked to my employee database. Essentially allowing me to choose multiple employees. I can then save the data and loop through the options and store it to a database.

The issue I am facing is when I go back to this page to now "Edit" the information, I am pre-loading the users that I selected prior but ALSO need to be able to support the AJAX searching for additional employees.

Has any one done anything like this or know a possible work around?

```
//Build preset carpool members
    <?php $counter = 1; foreach($fetchData->data as $data){ ?>

        var preload_data<?php echo $counter;?> = [

            <?php foreach($data->carpool->employees as $dataCP){ 
                $result .= "{ id: '".$dataCP->empID."', text: '".$dataCP->LastName.", ".$dataCP->FirstName."'},";
            } 
            echo rtrim($result, ',');
            ?>

            ];

         $('#carpool<?php echo $counter; ?>').select2({
                multiple: true,
                query: function (query){
                    var data = {results: []};

                    $.each(preload_data<?php echo $counter; ?>, function(){
                        if(query.term.length == 0 || this.text.toUpperCase().indexOf(query.term.toUpperCase()) >= 0 ){
                            data.results.push({id: this.id, text: this.text });
                        }
                    });

                    query.callback(data);
                },
                ajax: { 
                    url: "jsonUser.php",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: function (term) {
                        return {
                            term: term, // search term
                        };
                    },
                    results: function (data) { // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
                        return {results: data};
                    }
                },
            });

        $('#carpool<?php echo $counter; ?>').select2('data', preload_data<?php echo $counter; ?> )




    <?php $counter++; } ?>
```

The above code is pre-loading multiple select2 fields with the employee names just fine. However it doesn't allow the ajax part to work when there is pre-loaded data apparently.

Just trying to see if I am missing something with this?

Comment: In this case I would've tried to have the ajax call outside the `select2` and used that data instead of using the ajax option of the plugin directly.